# SQL Server 2012 Removing part of string before and after specific, repeating character

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

Would you please assist with a perplexing string operator problem?
I need to parse a NVARCHAR(32), not null column called MachineName from table dbo.Log.  The format is either:

- AA-BBB-CCC-DDD
- AA-BBB-CCCC-DDD
- AA-BBB-CCC-DDDD
- AA-BBB-CCCC-DDDD

I need the Result Set (as [Code]) to be either *CCC* or *CCCC*.
I consulted this article:
[http://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/removing-part-of-string-before-and-after-specific-character-using-transact-sql-string-functions/](http://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/removing-part-of-string-before-and-after-specific-character-using-transact-sql-string-functions/%22)

With this code:
    SELECT   DISTINCT [MachineName]
    ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([MachineName], CHARINDEX('-', [MachineName],6),     LEN([MachineName])), '-', '') AS [Code]
    FROM   [dbo].[Log]

My current Result Set is fine on the left, but the right needs refinement.

- CCCDDD
- CCCCDDDD

I would defintely appreciate your help!  Thank you in advance

Comment: Did the answer I provided help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can improvise on this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/588

```
with test as (
select cast('AA-BBB-CCC-DDD' as nvarchar(32)) as field1
union all
select cast('AA-BBB-CCCC-DDD' as nvarchar(32)) as field1
union all
select cast('AA-BBB-CCC-DDDD' as nvarchar(32)) as field1
union all
select cast('AA-BBB-CCCC-DDDD' as nvarchar(32)) as field1
)
select 
  substring(
    substring(field1,8,32), 
    1, 
    charindex('-', substring(field1,8,32))-1
  )
from test
```

Result:

```
CCC
CCCC
CCC
CCCC
```

With substring, we ignore the first 7 characters and start with 8th character. That'll give us `CCCC-DDD` and such. `charindex` will tell us the position of `-` in `CCCC-DDD` and such. We reapply substring on the substring; starting with first position and capturing all up until `-` was found.

In your case, you could do:

```
select distinct 
  substring(
    substring(MachineName,8,32), 
    1, 
    charindex('-', substring(MachineName,8,32))-1
  ) as Code
from dbo.Log
```

Comment: Hello Zedfoxus,   Thank you so much for your assistance.  I apologize for being delayed.    I don't use this forum often, but my usage is increasing.  I can work with this.